# Enable Fast export of Oracle Table Data in a csv file

Tags: unix, oracle11g

I am exporting 400M of Oracle Table data in a .csv file using sqlplus which is taking a lot of time.
Doing this by connecting to database using sqlplus and providing a file name.
And then invoking Select statement then captures the data in the file.
Query is a simple select statement to fetch records based on a predicate.

Is there a way of invoking multiple sqlplus commands from the same shell script parallelly and accessing the table data in batches(make sure no row is repeated in either of the batches).
Meaning - Fetch records in a batch of 1M(for ex) data parallelly (may be in a diff file) and then combine all the files in one in the end?

Looking for ways to reduce the run time of the script somehow. Any other suggestions are welcomed too.

Thanks

Comment: I thought it was you that was asking a question a couple days ago about optimizing the query where I was asking if you had done anything to profile the code to see exactly where the time is being spent (executing the query, fetching data over the network, etc.).  But I don't see that question in your history.  Do you know what is actually taking time?  Are you running the process on the database server?  Or are you running `SQL*Plus` on a different server and fetching data over the network?  You can rewrite the query to fetch data in pages.  That will require that you sort the data, however.

Comment: If the bottleneck is, as I believe you stated in your previous question, how quickly Oracle can run your query, it is unlikely that adding a sort requirement is going to help.  I assume if you are trying to optimize the process that this is something that you are doing regularly.  I'd take a step back and question why you are generating a CSV with millions of rows of data on a regular basis.  If this is part of an ETL operation, for example, you could move to generating an incremental file rather than a full file every day.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes I asked the same query. I reflected back on your question to understand the bottleneck.Adding the index hint  is not helping me, not sure how one day it resulted in less time . So my query is running with a full table scan in Parallel.
Now I am also trying to see if there can be a way of running the same query parallelly and get the data in batches over the network,
SQLPLUS is running on a different  server.I have provided values for arraysize/ rowprefetch to have some improvements.This data gets changed everyday and that is why we need the full load to be generated everyday.

Comment: So is the bottleneck the network?  CPU?  I/O?  How long does it take to generate the file if you run the process on the database server?  Does the output have to be a CSV file or could you, for example, use DataPump?  Trying to tune a process without knowing what is actually the bottleneck is really, really hard and seldom productive.  It's possible to request data in pages.  But if you're already using parallel query, spawning 400 sessions to each fetch 1 million rows of data and having each of those session generate a parallel plan and add a sort would be catastrophically bad.

Comment: Need data in csv files. Thank you , I will try to run the query on the db server and check. if Im getting the data in batches I will not use parallel sessions or use limited so as to make sure my total sessions are less.. 1M is just an example.

Comment: My larger point is that speculating randomly about performance issues without knowing the details of the specific performance issue is unlikely to be helpful.  We can speculate that running on the database server will be faster because it eliminates network traffic.  But beyond that, we're just speculating randomly.  Is it possible that you could roll your own parallelism that would be more efficient than Oracle's parallelism?  Sure.  Is it likely?  Not particularly.  Are there ways to tune the query?  Possibly.  Without knowing where the bottlenecks are, though, no help is likely possible.

Comment: Sure, Thanks Much. Give me sometime will paste the explain plan of my query to see if there is any scope.